# Group values within Slice to new type

Tags: go

I'm having an issue grouping user1 and user2 based on *location* onto a new type

```
type Chat struct {
location string
userName string
}

a := Chat{location:Cal, userName:"user1"}
b := Chat{location:Cal, userName:"user2"}
c := Chat{location:IL, userName:"user3"}

type result struct {
location string
chat []Chat
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you just want to group by the location string and create your result struct out of it, you can make use of a map:

```
type Chat struct {
    location string
    userName string
}

type Result struct {
    location string
    chat     []Chat
}

func main() {
    a := Chat{location: "Cal", userName: "user1"}
    b := Chat{location: "Cal", userName: "user2"}
    c := Chat{location: "IL", userName: "user3"}

    x := []Chat{a, b, c}
    m := make(map[string]Result)
    for _, c := range x {
        if val, ok := m[c.location]; ok {
            chats := append(val.chat, c)
            m[c.location] = Result{location: c.location, chat: chats}
        } else {
            m[c.location] = Result{location: c.location, chat: []Chat{c}}

        }
    }

    for k, v := range m {
        fmt.Printf("%s -> %v\n", k, v)
    }
}
```

That would return

```
Cal -> {Cal [{Cal user1} {Cal user2}]}
IL -> {IL [{IL user3}]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!